Subtract two images using alpha channel in python OpenCV
I want to subtract one image from the other using the first one's alpha channel.
The problem is really hard for me to explain by words, so please bear with me and my art.
Imagine that I have the following image. Let's call it image "A":

I also have another one, image "B":

B is an image of a terrifyingly complex shape. It also has some transparency, as depicted by the checkered background.
Now, imagine that after I place B on top of A, I get the following:

Here's the problem; I want to get the following output:

What's happening here is that after placing B on top of A, I want to preserve the area form image A where it intersects with image B's INNER transparent area, but remove parts of A where it intersects with B's OUTER transparent area. Also, B's RGB must be preserved.
How can I achieve this in python?

The simplest way by far is to make B's outer region opaque. IOW Only make B transparent where you want A to show through. It isn't a subtraction either more a case overlaying one in front of the other. What you see depends on the z-order.

@MartinBrown Mmm, making B's outer region opaque messes with the requirement to preserve B's RGB, because, well, it would have some RGB then.

I think you can use the tricks from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25734345/51685 to find the outer contour of B, then use it as a mask.

@AKX the OP's specification is unclear. B's RGB values are preserved! And they will be visible in the final merged image. It is B's transparency channel that has been altered. It is also unclear whether the OP's idea of "preserved" here means that it should appear in the resulting image after merging the two components. The question needs clarification.

@MartinBrown I'm not sure I'm following how you're proposing to then overlay the images on top of another if the outer region is made opaque? If the outer region has nonzero alpha and you just paste (source-over in Porter-Duff terms) that image on top of A, you'd get... whatever now-opaque color pasted onto the result?

@AKX According to his spec what he expects is never going to happen (where does the solid white come from?). The transparent part shows red through the centre of the mask. The parts inside the smaller square frame but outside the black curve are undefined (transparent?) and the remainder of image B outside that region with the smaller transparent object in are nowhere to be seen. The most likely outcome is that last image sat inside a red rectangular frame. But what goes in the undefined zone?

As I'm reading it, the "undefined" region (that is solid white in the output sketch) should be transparent, the colors of the outer contour of B should remain visible in the result, and whatever is transparent within B's contour should reveal A's colors.

Hi @AKX, thanks for your reply. I think I can use the outer contour as you suggested to do the magic - if the contours are accurate, given the complexity of the shape I'm dealing with. Will let you know how it goes. Thanks again!

When you post, please always post original images, so others can use them to show you how to do your task.

So as outlined in the comments, you can do this in 2 steps

find the outer part of B and make that white (instead of transparent)
overlay B on top of A as you normally would. Now since the outer part of B isn't white, it stays that way.

You can find the "outer part" of B (ie. the background) as opposed to other transparent areas in B by using the cv.connectedComponents() function (documentation here).
transparent_areas = B[:, :, 3] == 0 # mask of B outlining transparent areas. replace "== 0" with a threshold if those areas aren't completely transparent

n_components, transparent_connected_components = cv2.connectedComponents(transparent_areas.astype(np.uint8))


No we have the 2 connected components of the transparent area:

The non-transparent parts are always going to be labeled 0.
We just have to find which one(s) is/are the outer one(s) (here there is only one, but in a more complicated case, there could be several.)
That is simple: a connected component is a border one iff it contains a pixel at the border. So we just have to check which connected components the border pixels are in:
border_connected_components = np.concat([transparent_connected_components[0, :], 
   transparent_connected_components[-1, :] , 
   transparent_connected_components[:, 0], 
   transparent_connected_components[:, -1]])

border_connected_components = np.unique(border_connected_components)

# don't forget to remove 0 which represents non-transparent pixels
border_connected_components = border_connected_components[border_connected_components!=0]


Now we only have to set the border connected components to white

B[np.isin(transparent_connected_components, border_connected_components)] = (255, 255, 255, 255)



And to add them as you usually would

Oh wow! Thanks for the solution and the explanation! Now I can actually do much more with this solution.
Marked as the answer
